# Multiple deferred AJAX responses complete, but also using the iteration variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to

- Aggregate results from multiple `$.get` requests
- Insert a string based on the counter in the `for` loop for each request

The second part fails because I believe the multiple deferred requests means when they run, the for-loop is already complete.

Is there a way to pass in the variable so that the get request also knows which value of i it's on?

```
    var requests = [];
    var strings = ["Hi1","Hi2","Hi3","Hi4"]
    var total;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
      requests.push($.get('http://....', function(response) {
          // i here is always 4.
          console.log(i);
          total += response + strings[i];
      });
    }

    $.when.apply(null,requests).then(function() {
       // This works, but all of the strings have "Hi4".
       console.log(total);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to increment the counter for each response, you can do that as part of the callback instead of in the `for` loop, so it will increment as each call returns:

```
var requests = [];
var strings = ["Hi1","Hi2","Hi3","Hi4"]
var total;
var counter = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
  requests.push($.get('http://....', function(response) {
      total += response + strings[counter++];
  });
}
```

...though note that async responses aren't guaranteed to return in the same order that you sent them; if each counter value needs to correspond to a specific request, you may be better off handling each call separately with that specific value (or perhaps passing the counter value through to the server so you can read it as part of the response.)